# What should I set for X-Forwarded-Port in my Nginx config file?

Tags: nginx, keycloak

I'm using [Keycloak docs](https://www.keycloak.org/server/reverseproxy) to set up my Nginx reverse proxy correctly.

They recommend that we set all of the `X-Forwarded-*` options.

Here's is my Nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name accounts.$Domain;
    return 301 https://$NginxParamsServerName$NginxParamsRequestUri;
}

server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    server_name accounts.example.tld;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.tld/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.tld/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $what_should_i_put_here?
    }

    proxy_busy_buffers_size   512k;
    proxy_buffers   4 512k;
    proxy_buffer_size   256k;
}
```

What should I put there for `X-Forwardded-Port`?